# On div refresh text inside the input box shouldn't clear

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a div and it refreshes every 3 seconds. Inside that div there is an input box and whatever I type gets cleared out in 3 seconds. Is there a way for the text to remain inside the input box and not to get cleared out?

**index.js**

```
<div id="show_here"></div>
<script type ="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            $('#show_here').load('fetch.php')
        }, 3000);
    });
</script>
```

**fetch.php**

```
<div>
     // some code here 
    <input type="text" id="input" />
</div>
```

Input box needs to be inside that page since it is inside a while loop. Can this be done or i need to change my whole code to make this work?

Comment: Please format your question a little better; it's really hard to make sense of what you're trying to say, also your code looks really dodgy... To answer your question, why don't you just remove the code that makes your div refresh every 3 seconds? :)

Comment: why are you loading `fetch.php` in every 3 secs, I don't see anything updating there

Comment: are you entering into the textbox? if so why are you refreshing every 3sec?

Answer (score 2):

Preserve  and then set

```
setInterval(function() {
    my_val = $('#input').val();
    $('#show_here').load('fetch.php');
    $('#input').val(my_val); 
}, 3000);
```

Comment: #show_here what is / where  is  ?.. show the related code  ..  which relation there are between #show_here and #input?

Comment: the div `input` is not in the index page its inside the `fetch.php`
where as the `show_here` is inside the `index.php`

Comment: well show the proper part of index.php and tech.php